# With Open with Selenium Driver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

You know how in Python, you can open files using a with open() clause, is it possible to open selenium drivers using that clause so that it automatically closes the driver when you're done? Remembering to close the drivers that I open is something that I often forget and I'm just wondering if there's a better way.

This is what I mean by with open clause.

with open([INSERT FILE NAME HERE], [INSERT ACCESS MODE HERE]) as fileName:
[INSERT CODE]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't quite follow. What would the "file name" and "mode" be, if you wanted to use a Selenium driver this way? What exactly does "opening" and "closing" them entail?

Answer (score 0):

you would need [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) and code would be like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
class MySeleniumContextMgr():
    def __init__(self):
        print("build a driver")
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
         
    def __enter__(self):
        print("All coding logic")
        self.driver.get("https://simpleappdesigner.pythonanywhere.com/")
        time.sleep(10)
        return self
     
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print("Driver on quit!")
        self.driver.quit()
with MySeleniumContextMgr() as mydriver:
    print("done")
```

so print would be

```
build a driver
All coding logic
done
Driver on quit!
```